# Deeplinks with Ionic 4 and Electron

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, electron, ionic4, deep-linking

While planning to add deeplinks to a react app built with with electron and Ionic 4 I’ve encountered a possible issue.

Electron uses a protocol to detect a deeplink. Something like *“my-protocol://link-in-app.com”* so users can share the links in app with this protocol and open it in the app.

Ionic apps does not use the protocol, so it’s hard for me to wrap my head around the idea how should users share the links between mobile devices (ionic) and computer devices (electron).

Could there be any problem?

I would appreciate if someone could show me the right direction!

Thank you in advance <3

*note: i'm new to the implementation of deeplinks*